# Video crashes after pause

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, crash, flash-player

Whenever I pause a video, it crashes and displays this error

[image]

The learn more button redirects me to : https://support.google.com/youtube/?p=player_error1

I have tried (to no avail):

1. uninstalling and reinstalling flash. No luck. FYI I have checked on http://isflashinstalled.com/  and it confirms Shockwave Flash version 22 is installed.
2. switching to HTML5 player but found it was already set to that.
3. restarting the computer

Other info : occurs across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my windows 7 around two months back
Installed Adobe flash player 22 from [this link](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)

However, my control panel shows Adobe flash player Active X 22 and 22 NPAPI . No Adobe shockwave player.

This has worked for me hence I'm sharing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply DannyBoy. Could you please elaborate? That is the link I originally installed flash from. Are you saying I should install shockwave player (if that is a separate thing)? Thanks!

Comment: im saying active x is the key here. Alternatively you can try adobe flash cleanup

Comment: As in should I right click the video and change active X permissions? Thanks!  I have tried a flashplayer uninstall and reinstall but that didn't fix it unfortunately.